# How to list possible successor states for each state in OpenAI gym? (strictly for normal MDPs)

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

Is there a way to iterate through each state, force the environment to go to that state, and then take a step and then use the "info" dictionary returned to see what are all the possible successor states?

Or an even easier way to recover all possible successor states for each state, perhaps somewhere hidden?

I saw online that something called MuJoKo or something like that has a set_state function, but I don't want to create a new environment, I just want to set the state of the ones already provided by openAi gym.

Context: trying to implement topological order value iteration, which requires making a graph where each state has an edge to any state that any action could ever transition it to.

I realize that obviously in some games that's just not provided, but for the ones where it is, is there a way?

(Other than the brute force method of running the game and taking every step I haven't yet taken at whatever state I land at until I've reached all states and seen everything, which depending on the game could take forever)

This is my first time using OpenAi gym so please explain as detailed as you can. For example, I have no idea what Wrappers are.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, OpenAI gym does not have a method for supplying all possible successor states. Generally, that's sort of the point of creating an algorithm with OpenAI gym. You are training an agent to learn what the outcome of its actions are; if it can look into the future and know what the results of its actions are, it kind of defeats the purpose.

The brute force method you described is probably the easiest way to accomplish what you're describing.